# NProgress CSS for a custom image background

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, responsive-design, vue-nprogress

Hi I implemented NProgress in my Vue3 project for a Bakery and I wanted to customize the background of it with a custom sprite image i have of various baked goodies. Problem I have is image comes up but I still get that blue glow around the image. Anyone know how to get rid of it? I have attempted box-shadow with no success

[image: Here's how it looks like]

and heres my sass code

```
    height: 1rem
    background: $nav_background_image
    border: none
    box-shadow: none
```

I am unsure if this blue tint gets added on execution with the `*nprogress-busy*` class
Any help would be greatly apreciated

Answer (score 0):

This Works for me

```
#nprogress .bar {
  background: red;
}
#nprogress .peg {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #FFBB00, 0 0 5px #FFBB00;
}
```